# SML Warning: Type Vars Not Generalized when using Empty Lists or NONE option

Tags: sml, smlnj

I can't for the life of me figure out why the following SML function is throwing a Warning in my homework problem:

```
fun my_func f ls  = 
  case ls of 
  [] => raise MyException
  | head :: rest => case f head of 
                    SOME v => v
                    | NONE => my_func f rest

fun f a = if isSome a then a else NONE;
```

Whenever I call my_func with the following test functions:

```
my_func f [NONE, NONE];
my_func f [];
```

I always get the warning:

> *Warning: type vars not generalized because of
>      value restriction are instantiated to dummy types (X1,X2,...)*

Whenever I pass in an options list containing at least one SOME value, this Warning is not thrown. I know it must be something to do with the fact that I am using polymorphism in my function currying, but I've been completely stuck as to how to get rid of these warnings.

Please help if you have any ideas - thank you in advance!

Answer (score 24):

The *value restriction* referenced in the warning is one of the trickier things to understand in SML, however I will do my best to explain why it comes up in this case and try to point you towards a few resources to learn more.

As you know, SML will use type inference to deduce most of the types in your programs. In this program, the type of `my_func` will be inferred to be `('a -> 'b option) -> 'a list -> 'b`. As you noted, it's a polymorphic type. When you call `my_func` like this

```
myfunc f [NONE, SOME 1, NONE];
```

... the type variables `'a` and `'b` are instantiated to `int option` and `int`.

However when you call it without a value such as `SOME 1` above

```
myfunc f [NONE, NONE];
```

What do you think the type variables should be instantiated to? The types should be polymorphic -- something like `'t option` and `'t` for all types `'t`. However, there is a limitation which prevents values like this to take on polymorphic types.

SML defines some expressions as *non-expansive values* and only these values may take on polymorphic types. They are:

- literals (constants)
- variables
- function expressions
- constructors (except for `ref`) applied to non-expansive values
- a non-expansive values with a type annotation
- tuples where each field is a non-expansive value
- records where each field is a non-expansive value
- lists where each field is a non-expansive value

All other expressions, notably *function calls* (which is what the call to `my_func` is) **cannot be polymorphic**. Neither can references. You might be curious to see that the following does not raise a warning:

```
 fn () => my_func f [NONE, NONE];
```

Instead, the type inferred is `unit -> 'a`. If you were to call this function however, you would get the warning again.

My understanding of the reason for this restriction is a little weak, but I believe that the underlying root issue is mutable references. Here's an example I've taken from the MLton site linked below:

```
val r: 'a option ref = ref NONE
val r1: string option ref = r
val r2: int option ref = r
val () = r1 := SOME "foo"
val v: int = valOf (!r2)
```

This program does not typecheck under SML, due to the value restriction. Were it not for the value restriction, this program would have a type error at runtime.

As I said, my understanding is shaky. However I hope I've shed a little light on the issue you've run into, although I believe that in your case you could safely ignore the warning. Here are some references should you decide you'd like to dig deeper:

http://users.cis.fiu.edu/~smithg/cop4555/valrestr.html

http://mlton.org/ValueRestriction

(BTW the MLton site is **solid gold**. There's so much hidden away here, so if you're trying to understand something weird about SML, I highly recommend searching here because you'll likely turn up a lot more than you initially wanted)

Since it seems like you're actually using SML/NJ, this is a pretty handy guide to the error messages and warnings that it will give you at compile time:

http://flint.cs.yale.edu/cs421/smlnj/doc/errors.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your informed reply! I will look into your suggested resources for some further research, and will report back if I find a way to resolve this warning message. As you said, it may just not be possible for those certain test cases that are empty or just contain NONE, due to their polymorphic nature. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. A couple things you can do to remove the warning is (1) annotate with any type, which makes the value no longer polymorphic of course: `(my_func f [NONE, NONE]): int` or (2) realize this warning only occurs when entering a value like this in the REPL, and probably won't be raised in a larger program that calls `my_func` with other data.

Comment: Does Haskell have a version of this weirdness, or is lack of mutable references saving it?

Comment: I don't think it's exactly the same thing, but Haskell has the "monomorphism restriction"... I don't know Haskell well enough or understand the subtleties of this to know if they're really related. I think this has more to do with laziness, and can be turned off, so my guess is that it's only superficially  related.  http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction